# Using textbox for in foreach loop or for loop of the Model

Tags: list, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.textboxfor

I have a model in a view which is a list:

```
public PartialViewResult ParcialAlmacenProductoTerminado()
{
    var usuario = Fn.usuario_logeado.traerUsuario();
    ViewBag.usuario = usuario;
    List<op> ops = db.op.Where(x => x.temp != true && x.revisado == true && x.calidad == true && x.calidadRevision == true).ToList();

    return PartialView(ops);
}
```

And in my view I have this in the model area:

```
@model List<Produccion.Models.op>
```

I want to go through it with a `foreach` or a `for` (i already tried both) and create and html.textboxfor.

This is the attempt with the `for`:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.OrdenDeCompra[i], new { @class = "form-control obligatorio " })
}
```

and the one with the `foreach`:

```
@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.OrdenDeCompras, new { @class = "form-control obligatorio "})
}
```

none of them work

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is exactly is not working? What is the actual output and the ouput you expected?

Comment: it marks me an error in boths ways and i can't create de textboxfor, i'm gonna try add a screenshot

Comment: Assuming `OrdenDeCompra` is a property of your `op` model, then its `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].OrdenDeCompra, new { ... })` (and you cannot use a `foreach` loop - refer [Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/post-an-html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Comment: @RicardoSanchezSantos please do not add screenshots of error messages. It is better when you add them as text. The error messages should also be in English.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that solve my problem